# WPF toolkit datagrid spreadsheet

Tags: wpf, datagrid, spreadsheet, toolkit

I would like to add excel spreadsheet functionality to the WPF toolkit datagrid, can this be done?

I am building a wpf client-server application and I want client tohave  wpf toolkit datagrid cells which would behave like excel spreadsheet cells would behave... Meaning they would have formulas and such... just like the spreadsheet would.

I am trying to accomplish this without the usage of Farpoint datagrid product that i already use for a winforms client-server application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically it could be done, but it will require a fair bit of coding (I'm talking weeks to months here rather than days). You could possibly knock up a simple implementation using limited functions reasonably quickly, but you'll soon start to run into problems. If I were you, I'd look into alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Did you have a look at [Clear Office](http://www.clearoffice.com)?
It is similar to farpoint but written in WPF. Very easy to use. No COM interop.